# How to tag several friends in a photo using Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, tags

From Facebook Developer document, I find that
"You can specify which user to tag using two methods: in the URL path as `PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID`, or in a URL parameter as `PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID`. To add several tags at once, you can specify a tags property which contains an array of tags like so `PHOTO_ID/tags?tags=[{"id":"1234"}, {"id":"12345"}]`. Currently, you cannot tag a Page in a photo using this API."

Here is my code.

```
NSString *photoID = @"267766096670674";    

[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tags?tags=[{\"id\":\"%@\"},{\"id\":\"%@\"}]?access_token=%@", photoID, @"100001965796318", @"100004119154586", self.facebook.accessToken]
                          andParams:nil 
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

I get the error as following
"Error message: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x3f55a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x3f5c10 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}"

Due to the document, tag one friend is OK. But why can't I tag several friends at once?

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the problem, but the query string you’re building there is wrong – you have a `?` before the parameter name `access_token`, where it should be a `&`. If fixing this doesn’t make the problem go away, then try URL-encoding the value of the `tags` parameter properly.

Comment: Thanks alot. But I use '&' to replace '?', this doesn't solve the problem. And I really don't understand "URL -encoding the value of the tags parameter properly", can you give me an example?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+url+encoding And for how to do it in the language your are using, please do the research yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use "tag_uid" to replace "id" and encode the url, so it works! I find that \" can not be used directly in url.

Answer (score 0):

The key in the api should be 'tag_uid' instead of 'to'.
Therefore the API should be:

PHOTO_ID/tags?tags=[{"tag_uid":"1111111111111"},{"tag_uid":"222222222"}]

Comment: Thank a lot. It solves the problem when using the Facebook API Explorer. But I copy the paramater to XCode like the following

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot. It solves the problem when using the Facebook API Explorer. But I copy the paramater to XCode like the following

```
    NSString *testString = @"267766096670674/tags?tags=[{\"tag_uid\":\"100001965796318\"},{\"tag_uid\":\"100004119154586\"}]&access_token=BAAC3gS8qGCUBADoG8Rvh1jAfWJQmAW6BenV6KXkcQThKquvav7v1eSZB4MxHefH3hwt6JHd44Rz9FWhXVCNZAAmUGzVz6OcaKvxUZA0tCDlKU9Wj7o0hQo8eB7GgdoXaWrkx79oRzqKyjF7O9cX";
NSLog(@"%@", testString);
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:testString
                          andParams:nil 
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

It doesn't work. But it works with the Graph API Explorer Tool and I don't know why.

Comment: Please edit your question to update on your progress rather than posting an answer.